# Select distinct values for a particular column choosing arbitrarily from duplicates

Tags: sql, db2

I have health data relating to deaths.  Individual should die once maximum.  In the database they sometimes don't; probably because causes of death were changed but the original entry was not deleted. I don't really understand how this was allowed to happen, but it has. So, as a made up example, I have:

```
 Row_number | Individual_ID | Cause_of_death        | Date_of_death
------------+---------------+-----------------------+---------------
     1      |     1         | Stroke                | 3 march 2008     
     2      |     2         | Myocardial infarction | 1 jan 2009  
     3      |     2         | Pulmonary Embolus     | 1 jan 2009
```

I want each individual to have only one cause of death.

In the example, I want a query that returns row 1 and either row 2 or row 3 (not both).  I have to make an arbitrary choice between rows 2 and 3 because there is no timestamp in any of the fields that can be used to determine which is the revision; it's not ideal but is unavoidable.

I can't make the SQL work to do this. I've tried inner joining distinct Individual_ID to the other fields, but this still gives all the rows.  I've tried adding a 'having count(Individual_ID) = 1' clause with it.  This leaves out people with more than one cause of death completely.  Suggestions on the internet seem to be based on using a timestamped field to choose the most recent, but I don't have that.

IBM DB2. Windows XP. Any thoughts gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `MIN` (or `MAX`) against the cause of death. (and the date of death, if they died on two different dates)

```
SELECT IndividualID, MIN(Cause_Of_Death), MIN (Date_Of_Death)
from deaths
GROUP BY IndividualID
```

Comment: When doing this trick against two columns you might receive values from two different rows in the single output row. This is probably a bug.

Comment: Yes, but presumably MIN(date_of_death) has to be correct? (Not a bug though)

Comment: @usr - If one person has more than one date of death I'd say that the data has a huge problem.

Comment: The OP says this is the case. The data is not clean. This query might produce the earlier cause and the latter date. If the dates are always the same your approach is best.

Comment: It seems the OP is not particularly bothered with accuracy, only with the data been correct in form.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I'm 'not bothered with accuracy' in the sense that there are a fairly small number of cases where this problem arises. The changes to the date of death are quite small in real terms -- they tend in reality to be clarifications rather than complete changes and the dates themselves don't change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know DB2 so I'll answer in general. There are two main approaches:

```
select *
from T
join (
 select keys, min(ID) as MinID
 from T
 group by keys
) on T.ID = MinID
```

And

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by keys) as r
from T
where r = 1
```

Both return all rows, no matter if duplicate or not. But they returns only one duplicate per "key".

Notice, that both statements are pseudo-SQL.

Comment: In the first version you don't want the `HAVING` clause - as otherwise you're excluding the 'correct' cases from the results. In the second version you don't alias the `ROW_NUMBER()` calculation. Also, in most RDBMS, you can't reference the `ROW_NUMBER()` result in the `WHERE` clause *(doing so changes which result have `ROW_NUMBER()` applied to them, which creates a circular reference)*, instead you need a sub-query and then filter the rows in the outer query.  `ROW_NUMBER()` also requires a `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the first one and clarified that this is pseudo-SQL. I don't know DB2 so I'm not qualified to produce real SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The row_number() approach is probably preferable from a performance standpoint.  Here is usr's example, in DB2 syntax:

```
select * from (
       select T.*, row_number() over (partition by Individual_ID) as r
           from T
   )
   where r=1;
```

Comment: Note: an ORDER BY clause is not required for ROW_NUMBER(), at least in DB2 9.7, which I am using.